# Ayuda al recuperar datos desde un controlador con Spring?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

Tengo el siguiente método que me regresa una lista, de la cual quiero recuperar un campo y si me lo trae, uso el model para mandar el valor de ese campo al jsp, pero no muestra nada en consola de navegador

```html
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value= "/obtenerLista", method=(RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET), consumes= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public JsonResponseGeneric<TipoCliente> llenaLista(@RequestBody JsonResponse datosJson,  Model model){

    ObjectMapper object = new ObjectMapper();
    ClaseDTO parametro = object.readValue(datosJason.getJson(), ClaseDTO.class);
    
     JsonResponseGeneric<TipoCliente> listaCliente = new JsonResponseGeneric<TipoCliente>();
     
     List<TipoCliente> llenaLista = srvicio.consultaLista(parametro.getServicio());
     model.addAttribute("valorTipo", llenaLista.get(0).getIdTipoServicio());
     listaCliente.setLista(llenaLista);
     
    return listaCliente;
}
```

y en mi jsp lo recupero en un input hidden

```html
<input type="hidden" id="inputTipo" name="inputTipo"  value="${llenaLista.get(0).getIdTipoServicio()}"



console.log("id" +$("#inputTipo").val());
```

Como le puedo hacer para recuperar ese dato y mandarlo a mi jsp?
Ojala puedan apoyarme

Comment: Tienes una anotación @ResponseBody, eso suele significar que que estás devolviendo un JSON y no delegando en un JSP. Se usa para responder llamadas desde un API REST o para responder a peticiones AJAX.

Comment: Entonces cuál sería la forma correcta?

Comment: Sinceramente no acabo de entender el escenario y me faltan datos, pero si llegas al JSP desde otro controlador, deberías añadir al ViewAndModel ese valor